# How count all id's with same name and add to array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I need count of same ids.

```
<span id='name'>Something</span>

<span id='name'>Something</span>

<span id='name'>Something</span>

<span id='name'>Something</span>

<span id='name'>Something</span>
```

.............
and add to array:

```
<span id='name[1]'>Something</span>

<span id='name[2]'>Something</span>

<span id='name[3]'>Something</span>

<span id='name[4]'>Something</span>

<span id='name[5]'>Something</span>
```

......
Please help me with this...Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't have elements with the same ID, the point of ID's is that they're unique. You should use classes instead `<span class="name">`

Comment: I think this will cause issues when you have elements with the same ID...

Comment: IDs can't be used more than once.  They are, by definition, unique and should never be used more than once per page.  If you do you'll have an invalid DOM and scripting against it will not be reliable.  Square brackers [] are also invalid for IDs.  Better to give elements that share common attributes a class and to give each individual item in that class a unique ID such as <div class="something" id="name_1">. Once you've done this you can use PHP's DOMDocument (server side) or jQuery (client side) to grab the set of divs by their class name.

Comment: And I _guess_ that's why this question exists: How to fix the errors in a given dataset ;-)

Comment: Is the document otherwise valid Xhtml (except the duplicated Ids)?

Comment: Do you want a server-side solution (PHP, in your case) or a client-side solution (JavaScript/jQuery)?

Comment: I agree with @fin1te and @michelgotta, having so many elements with the same ID might blow your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML to `<span class="name">` and use this jQuery code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.name').each(function(index) {
                $(this).attr('id', 'name['+index+']');
            });
        });
```

If you use `#name`the `$('#name').each()` would stop after the first element because the ID should always be unique.

Answer (score 0):

the id of element has to be unique. to get the element of same id use this method

```
var all_elem = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var same_id = array();
var index = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < all_elem.length;i++) {
    if(all_elem[i].id=="name") {
        same_id[index++] = all_elem[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time, please don't use `<br/>` to break lines and format your code (neither use `&lt;` if you don't want that entity literally), just indent your code by 4 spaces (e.g., using the code button `{}`). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could...

```
$('span#name').each(function(i){
    this.id += '[' + i + ']';
})
```

but if possible, as I am sure you are aware because of the question, you should change your id to class, then set id separately.

Also, I don't know that `[` and `]` are valid in id. You should use `name-1` instead if possible.